# How to get the user profile info thats associated with the user session ID?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, session-variables

I have the following code when a user login I want the user profile data pulled from the database to match the user login session variable. How do you get the user profile info thats associated with the user $session_id?

My code snippet:

```
 <?php
    bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    include('inc/database.php');
    include('session.php');
    $userDetails=$userClass->userDetails($session_id);
    $db = getDB();
    $sql = "SELECT
              gamerEmail
            , gamerContent

            ,p.gpd_id
            , p.content

            FROM gamers g
            INNER JOIN
            gamerProfileData p
             where gamers.gamer_id = gamerProfileData.gpd_id ;

            ORDER BY gamer_id = {$_SESSION['gamer_id']},  gpd_id";
    $gamer_profile = $db->query($sql);

                foreach ($gamer_profile as $gamer_info) {

                       $gamer_info['something'];  //I'm stuck....

    ?>

                    <tr>
                    <td>Gamer Profile ID: <?php echo $gamer_info['gpd_id'] ?> </td>
                    <td>Gamer Profile Info: <?php echo  $gamer_info['info'] ?> </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: I dont see a question! What is the problem?

Comment: `ORDER BY gamer_id = {$_SESSION['gamer_id']}` that should be in the `where`, not the `order`. You also should parameterize.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry about that I updated my question.

Comment: Your current `where` should be an `on` and your where should check the `userid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your query!

And once your query works just place the table row output inside the while loop

```
<?php
bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
include('inc/database.php');
include('session.php');

$userDetails=$userClass->userDetails($session_id);
$db = getDB();

$sql = "SELECT gamerEmail, gamerContent, p.gpd_id, p.content, p.info
        FROM gamers g
        INNER JOIN gamerProfileData p ON gamers.gamer_id = gamerProfileData.gpd_id

        WHERE gamer_id = {$_SESSION['gamer_id']}
        ORDER BY gpd_id";

$gamer_profile = $db->query($sql);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($gamer_profile as $gamer_info) {
?>

    <tr>
        <td>Gamer Profile ID: <?php echo $gamer_info['gpd_id'] ?> </td>
        <td>Gamer Profile Info: <?php echo  $gamer_info['info'] ?> </td>
    </tr>
<?php
} // endwhile

echo '</table>';
?>
```

> Its not totally clear where the `info` column lives, i.e. in the `gamers` or `gamerProfileDate` table. You may need to correct that in the query.

Comment: I do need to clean this up a bit.  I made this a bit more complicated. I am going to add the info column in the same table.